# What is the lifetime incidence for tendinopathy for regular humans?

Tags: statistics, tendinopathy

I wonder what the [lifetime incidence](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/29310/43) is for tendinopathy for regular humans (e.g., not only athletes).

---

What I have found so far:

I found the lifetime incidence for Achilles tendinopathy in {1}:

> The cumulative lifetime incidence of Achilles tendinopathy was reported as 52% among elite runners compared to 6% in the general population.

I'm looking for the lifetime incidence for any tendinopathy (e.g., not only Achilles tendinopathy).

---

References:

- {1} Florit D, Pedret C, Casals M, Malliaras P, Sugimoto D, Rodas G. Incidence of Tendinopathy in Team Sports in a Multidisciplinary Sports Club Over 8 Seasons. J Sports Sci Med. 2019 Nov 19;18(4):780-788. PMID: 31827363; PMCID: [PMC6873129](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6873129/).

Answer (score 2):

My estimate is **~25% of lifetime incidence for tendinopathy in the general population** based on the following 2 studies.

1. The lifetime incidence for Achilles tendinopathy in 6% in the general population {2}.
2. The presentation {1} mentions the yearly symptomatic tendinopathy incidence for the most typical sites of tendon injuries:

   - Achilles: 2.35/1,000 {1}
   - Patellar: 1.6/1,000 {1}
   - Adductor: 1.22/1,000 {1}
   - Gluteal: 4.22/1,000 {1}
   - Plantar Fascia: 2.44/1,000 {1}
   - Elbow: 3/1,000 {1}
   - Shoulder: 3/1,0003/1,000 {1}

Given that there exist at least 6 other joints where tendon injuries happen with a similar incidence as in the Achilles tendon,  the lifetime incidence for tendinopathy is ~25% (7 injury locations*6% of lifetime incidence for each of them = 36% lifetime incidence for any, lifetime incidence  But some people may have more than 1 injured location, hence ~25%).

As a result, unsurprisingly, tendon injuries account for at least 7% of physician visits in the United States {3}.

---

References:

- {1} Dry Needling for Tendinopathy 1.16.18 - Academy of Orthopaedics https://www.orthopt.org/uploads/content_files/files/Dry%20Needling%20for%20Tendinopathy%201.16.18.pdf  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190406233117/https://www.orthopt.org/uploads/content_files/files/Dry%20Needling%20for%20Tendinopathy%201.16.18.pdf))
- {2} Florit D, Pedret C, Casals M, Malliaras P, Sugimoto D, Rodas G. Incidence of Tendinopathy in Team Sports in a Multidisciplinary Sports Club Over 8 Seasons. J Sports Sci Med. 2019 Nov 19;18(4):780-788. PMID: 31827363; PMCID: [PMC6873129](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6873129/).
- {3} Kane SF, Olewinski LH, Tamminga KS. Management of Chronic Tendon Injuries. Am Fam Physician. 2019 Aug 1;100(3):147-157. PMID: 31361101.
  https://www.aafp.org/afp/2019/0801/p147.html